# Apache refusing to change DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, zend-server, documentroot

I've installed Zend Server CE 5.1.0 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit in its default location, meaning the path to my htdocs is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs`. Not something that I would like to type each time I check out a project from SVN in Eclipse or something.

I'd like to set the DocumentRoot to a different folder, namely `D:\www`.

**What I've done**

I edited `conf/httpd.conf`, with the significant lines being:

```
DocumentRoot "D:\www"
<Directory "D:\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I edited `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to add a virtual host:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot              D:\www
    ServerName                localhost
    ServerAlias               localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
    SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot              D:\www\UmbraCMS
    ServerName                umbracms.local
    ServerAlias               umbracms.local
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
    SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN umbracms.local
</VirtualHost>
```

I edited `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to add this line:

```
127.0.0.1 umbracms.local
```

And I also added a PHP project to `D:\www\UmbraCMS`. And restarted Apache. Actually, I restarted the computer, too, just in case.

**What's supposed to happen**

After typing `http://umbracms.local/` in the browser's address bar, I want to see my PHP project launch, obviously.

**What's actually happening**

No matter whether whether I type `http://umbracms.local/` or `http://localhost/`, I'm taken to the test zend page, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\index.html`, as if neither DocumentRoot was changed nor name-based virtual hosting worked.

Interestingly, when I put another project in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\bugraid\` and then, in the browser, typed `http://localhost/bugraid`, the project actually opened, or at least tried to, as it completely ignored the project's `.htaccess` file.

**Extra considerations**

Zend Server's Apache version is 2.2.16, PHP version is 5.3.0

I've installed MySQL CE 5.5.13 separately, and it works, both from command line and via MySQL Workbench.

I have XAMPP installed, but none of its components are started up. It's got its own install of Apache 2.2.17 and MySQL 5.5.1. PHP version is 5.3.5 (I think).

**Question**

Have you had a similar situation before? What else might need taking care of in order to have Zend Server's Apache use `D:\www` as document root for my PHP projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't vista play tricks with administrator-owned files that your user edits, basically making copies that only your user sees?  I believe it is "filesytem redirection" -- try runas + administrator and you'll see httpd.conf is not really changed.

Comment: Interesting info, I wasn't aware of this. I'll check it as soon as possible. However, I tried this on another machine running Windows 7 Professional 32 bit (at work) and it worked as expected. Might this be a phenomenon specific to W7 Ultimate, or perhaps the 64 bit version?

Comment: OK, confirmed. Thank you. I wouldn't have guessed it without your help.